# How should questions about syntax be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags

For questions about language syntax, we currently have a few tags:

- [syntax](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/syntax)
- [tokens](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tokens)
- *Feel free to add more as more questions are asked*

What situations should these tags be used in, and what new ones might we need?

Comment: Suggest making this community wiki

Comment: @user16217248 I've asked the mods.

Comment: Oh wait, we don't _have_ mods!

Comment: Maybe a community manager could do it.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax should be used for all of them. Then use normal tags. No special rules or anything.